# Выровнять текст по разным сторонам в одном div'e

Tags: html, css

Нужно выровнять текст в одном диве. Заголовок - по центру. Содержимое - слева. Пробовал через span, ну конечно же не получилось.

```
<div style="text-align: center">Заголовок </br> Содержимое </div>
```

Здесь всё по центру, а нужно чтобы содержимое было с левой стороны.

Answer (score 1):

Правильный и валидный вариант:

```css
h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Заголовок</h1>
  <p>Содержимое</p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

как вариант просто обернуть в `div`:

```css
.head {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <div class="head">Заголовок</div>
   <div>Содержимое</div>
</div>
```

Ну или с Вашим кодом(не понятно что значит в одном `div`е):

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
   Заголовок
   <div style="text-align: start;">Содержимое</div>
</div>
```

Comment: То есть, в любом случае нужно создавать второй див?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда иначе не получится, Вам нужно выделить то что должно вести себя по другому в блочный элемент чтобы им управлять, иначе все выравнивания будет прерывать родитель. Плюс я не думаю что у Вас будет слово "содержимое" при верстке, а будет много какой-либо информации либо вёрстки, так что не вижу ничего плохого

Comment: Спасибо, я просто думал можно содержимое обернуть в span.

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда пожалуйста :)